# Different access to property for different classes

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have a base (abstract) class `Component`. I want to control access to properties of derived classes such that everyone gets read access, but write access is only allowed by certain classes.

Those 'certain classes' are currently anything that implements the abstract base class `MessageHandler<TMessage>`. Ideally I'd also like an class implementing `IMessageHandler` to be able to get access, but I think that makes the requirement a bit tougher.

This will run on the xbox and so I want to avoid creating temporary objects (such as read-only copies). I also want to minimise the number of method calls to get at the value that's read/written to.

The `Component` class and `MessageHandler<TMessage>` classes are currently in their own assemblies, both of which will be referenced by other projects when using my API.

I'm guessing I'm going to have to change my model somehow, but I can't get my head around it.

```
public abstract class Component
{

}

public class DerivedComponentA : Component
{
    int property {get; set;}
}

public abstract class MessageHandler<TMessage>
{

}

public class IntMsghandler : MessageHandler<int>
{
    void DoThing(DerivedComponentA derivedComponentA)
    {
        derivedComponentA.property = 5; // Allowed
    }
}

public class AnyClass // Doesn't inherit MessageHandler, or implement IMessageHandler
{
    void DoThing(DerivedComponentA derivedComponentA)
    {
        derivedComponentA.property = 5; // Not Allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: If anything is unclear, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: It's not clear to what you want to restrict access. Where are the properties you want to restrict access to?

Comment: @Matten: That's illegal. You can't change the access modifiers of overridden members.

Comment: It seems like what you want actually isn't inheritance in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *isolation* (based on question you made and what I understood) is made based on base class definition (*if any*). That means the isolation *should* start from it.

Or, if you say, that if some `class X` implements `MessageHandler` should be able to act in several way on `class Y` type objects. That, imo, means that there is a tough relation between 
`class Y` and `MessageHandler`.

This leads to think me that you can do somehting like this:

- *only* public `get` on the properties of  `DerivedComponentA`
- in `MessageHandler` define a generic `protected SetProperty(Component compo, string propertyName, object propertyValue)` and set required property with reflection.

In this way only possible way to set a property on *any* `Component` derived class is by using `MessageHandler` method, so will be available only for those ones who derive from it. For the rest of available types you provide *only* `public get` (readonly) poperty for reading data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you work with interfaces here. Have one read only interface `IReadOnlyComponent` that has a read only property and an `IWritableComponent : IReadOnlyComponent` that adds a `Set` method for the property.
The abstract base class `Component` implements `IWritableComponent` and thus has the read only property and the `Set` method.
Pass the component instance as `IWritableComponent` only to classes that inherit from `MessageHandler` or implement `IMessageHandler` and pass it as `IReadOnlyComponent` to all other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just control the setter like this:

```
public string Prop {
  get { return ...; }
  set { if (!(this is MessageHandler<TMessage>)) 
           throw Exception(...);
        .... setter code;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm probably not clear, the property is on the component class, not the message handler (although the message handler is the one that wants to change the value). Code added.

Comment: Also, ideally i want it compile-time enforced (although don't know how realistic that is).